# Setting up a new job using ubuntu's crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have little experience with setting up cron jobs.

I need to configure a cron job to delete all files starting with the filename `'sess_'` from the `'/tmp'` folder every hour.

If I fire up the crontab using `crontab -e` and write the following code:

```
0 */1 * * * find /tmp/ -name "sess_*" -delete
```

will that work?

Does the syntax look correct?
Do I need to restart anything? (i.e - Apache)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `*/1` is the same as `*` in the cron definition so

```
0 * * * *  ...
```

would work the same way.

---

In find the `-delete` will delete the files as you request but it may not be what you want. You can test your find command by running it from the command line without the `-delete` option

```
find /tmp/ -name "Sess_*"
```

which will give you the list of files that would be acted upon.

---

Better still might be to look at the /etc/cron.d/php5 file which does the same thing for session files located in /var/lib/php5. Note that it only deletes files that are older than the system's maxlifetime by using the -cmin option ...

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

By doing it this way you won't blindly delete session files that are in use.